# Miracast in Windows Server 2012 R2 (Devices in Charms side bar missing)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, miracast

I have, so far been able to add my TV to my devices list in Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter edition, However unlike in Windows 8/8.1 I am not able to Project my display content to the TV as I dont see that option in my windows charm side bar.

How can i get my miracast working with my TV ?

Comment: You can always use the same method you used in Windows 7 to do this.  Are you sure you have added that Windows Feature?  Windows Server often has features like this removed by default.

Comment: If i am not wrong, Windows 7 does not support Miracast out of the box. I am not sure if I have add a feature to enable this, I simply went into 'Add Device' in control panel and it worked just like in Windows 8. Its the projection bit to the TV which is missing.

Comment: I have my TV listed in my devices list, so its just case of switching my display to my TV.

Comment: Have you added the "Desktop Experience" feature to the Server?